# Use Plone's authentication mechanism to login to other sites

Tags: plone, single-sign-on, sugarcrm

I am using Plone and Sugar CRM. I want to allow users to only have a single username and password across both systems. When they change their password in Plone they should not have to change it in Sugar CRM. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure both to authenticate against an LDAP server.

Answer (score 3):

If you want single sign on, you can also look at Plone 4's mod_auth_tkt support. Basically, Plone will set a cookie that is compatible with the auth_tkt standard. Other systems (such as Apache or nginx as fronting web servers) can use the same cookie format to authenticate a user.